# NDVI temporal analysis error in Sentinel

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, time, analysis, sentinel

I need to do a temporal analysis of NDVI with Sentinel images from 2019 to 2023, using monthly composites and extract the NDVI value for random points created. However, it is generating empty data.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/6875322c6bbe17414d3e4a4163001dfd

```js
var linha = ee.FeatureCollection("projects/doutorado-397514/assets/pama_corte");



function calcndvi(image) {
  return image.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).rename('NDVI');
}



function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;  // Bits 10 e 11 de nuvens e cirrus, respectivamente.
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0).and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));
  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}



var startDate = '2018-01-01';
var endDate = '2023-12-31';



var sentinelCollection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
  .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
  .filterBounds(linha.geometry())
  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 20)) // Filtragem adicional por cobertura de nuvens
  .map(maskS2clouds)
  .map(calcndvi);

var monthlyNDVI = ee.ImageCollection(
  ee.List.sequence(2018, 2023).map(function(year) {
    return ee.List.sequence(1, 12).map(function(month) {
      return sentinelCollection.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(year, year, 'year'))
        .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(month, month, 'month'))
        .median()
        .set('year', year, 'month',
month);
});
}).flatten()
);


var buffer15 = linha.map(function(feature) {
return feature.buffer(15);
});



function generateRandomPoints(segment) {
var numPoints = 100; // Definir número de pontos por segmento
return ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints(segment.geometry(), numPoints);
}


var randomPoints = buffer15.map(generateRandomPoints).flatten();


if (randomPoints.size().getInfo() === 0) {
  print('Nenhum ponto aleatório foi gerado. Verifique a coleção de linhas e o buffer.');
} else 
  
  var ndviPoints = monthlyNDVI.map(function(image) {
    return image.sampleRegions({
      collection: randomPoints,
      properties: ['year', 'month'],
      scale: 10
    });
  }).flatten();
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Please include the actual code as a formatted text because links tend to not work after some time.

Comment: Hi Nikos, thank you. I edited my question and copied the code.

Comment: `Collection.loadTable: Collection asset 'projects/doutorado-397514/assets/pama_corte' not found.` you need to share the asset if you want us to run the code to reproduce the error